# View goes under tab-bar - iOs7 Autolayout

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, autolayout

This must be just another autolayout question. I did do all I can think of to find out what is wrong but nothing seems to right. Maybe I'm missing something or doing something really stupid.

I added an UIImageView to a ViewController, set the autolayout constraints of the ImageView in Xcode. To see the borders, i added an IBOutlet to viewcontroller and set border width of Image to 2.0 and border color to red. It works well in iOS 6, in both landscape and portrait mode. When i run the same in iOS 7, the bottom part of the view goes under tab bar.. heavy sigh. Im hoping this is something configurable in the UI, rather than making code change. I unchecked  "Unchecked" Adjust scroll view insets for ViewController , also made sure that the bottom Space ( Vertical Space) of the ImageView is set to the top of Botton Layout Guide, as mentioned in apple ios migration guide. Im not sure what else to do and im not feeling lucky. Can someone please take a look ? I already spent few days on this and im not reaching anywhere. Here are few screen shots if it helps.

Thank you for your time.

Unfortunately stackoverflow wont let me add images unless i have brownie points :( 
hopefully these links would work

[iOS 7 screenshot](https://db.tt/p9u4Bxv4)
[iOS 6 Screenshot](https://db.tt/LHMSYayT)

Comment: Have you tried setting a Height Constraint on the imageView in the interface builder ?

Comment: i want the imageView to resize with the orientation, so i didnt define a specific height. The constraints i defined are Trailing and Leading to SuperView, 'Top Space' to the bottom of Top Layout guide and 'Bottom Space' to the top of Bottom Layout guide. Is it required to define height ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this code in another post and it resolved my issue.

`- (UIRectEdge)edgesForExtendedLayout {
    return [super edgesForExtendedLayout] ^ UIRectEdgeBottom;
}`

Answer (score 5):

There is an option I believe called 'under bottom bars' uncheck this and it should work.

[image]